# Android ACTION_EXIT_CAR_MODE not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to detect ENTER and EXIT of car mode using UiModeManager. But when I enable/disable "**Hands-free mode**" in my Samsung S4 BroadcastReceiver not invoked.Here is my code

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.titut.car"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />


    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <receiver
            android:name=".CarModeReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.ENTER_CAR_MODE" />
                <action android:name="android.app.action.EXIT_CAR_MODE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**CarModeReceiver.java**

```
public class CarModeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "CarModeReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action != null) {
            if (action.equals(UiModeManager.ACTION_ENTER_CAR_MODE)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Entering car mode!");
            } else if (action.equals(UiModeManager.ACTION_EXIT_CAR_MODE)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Leaving car mode!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Reference : https://github.com/twaddington/android-obd-logger

Any suggestion/fix would help me lot.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but try changing

```
android:exported="false"
```

to

```
android:exported="true"
```